# Can Bluetooth headphones be used on a PS3?

Tags: ps3

My Turtlebeach headset broke and I don't have much cash to buy a new pair.

Is it possible to use a pair of Bluetooth headphones on my PS3 to hear in game sound? Or do I have to buy a new headset?

Comment: We don't do product recommendations.  The best we can do for you is tell you if bluetooth will work on your PS3 or not.  I'm pretty sure it won't.

Comment: you don't have to do anything. Just do what you want, why are you asking us? I recommend this: https://www.videoguys.com.au/Shop/p/28146/sennheiser-hd-700-open-circumaural-dynamic-stereo-headphones-504963.html?gclid=CKCn7vWrtMcCFQYDvAodXxwKBQ

Comment: I don't recommend using wireless headphones. I recommend [this](http://www.audioaffair.co.uk/abyss-ab-1266-headphones-deluxe-package)

Answer (score 3):

It'll work. sure. At least, it should, especially since the traditional in-ear phone-pairing bluetooth always worked. Put your bluetooth device into Pairing mode, and go to the settings tab in the XMB menu and find bluetooth settings, and you should be able to pair from there. I think you can set it up to filter any audio through it too, if I'm not mistaken.